# Casting with a variable Type

Tags: c#, casting

I try to cast a variable type of Object int to a var.

My try is:

```
var dummy = (items[items.Count() - 1].GetType()) items[items.Count()-1];
```

I dunno what I'm doing wrong, i cant see my error, but the debugger says that only assign, decrement and "new Object"-expressions can be used as a command... But that's what I'm doing...

Can somebody show me my error?
Many thanks in advance, and sorry for that "beginnerquestion".

Comment: This is not possible. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a Arraylist with differnt Typs of Objects and i try to cast them into a var, to assign them values from another Lists which have only one type of Objects. But ok... then i have to do a "typeof" switch. Thanks.

Comment: band your question! We just don't know what are you doing and what you want to do.

Comment: You wrote a qustion about casting, but then in your post, the question you've ended up asking was about your compiler error.  a more appropriate title would have been something like `only assign, decrement and "new Object"-expressions can be used as a command`

Comment: `var` is not a type.  You can't convert something to type `var` because it doesn't exist.  `var` is simply a keyword that says, "Make the type of this variable be the compile time type of the expression to the right of the `=` operator so that I don't need to bother to type it out."  It will still be a fixed compile time type.

Comment: alternatively, you could have fixed your compiler error, and then actually asked the question about casting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**Convert.ChangeType**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx)

```
var obj = Convert.ChangeType(d, items[items.Count() - 1].GetType());
```

Comment: in light of your post, i've -1'ed the OP, for being inconsistent in his question

Comment: Wow. Thanks. That works and is much shorter than a "typeof"switch.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the source of the error you're experiencing.

Your compiler sees `(items[items.Count() - 1].GetType())` as an expression, rather than a casting statement, so what it sees is

```
getAValue() (items[items.Count() - 1].GetType())
```

which doesn't make any sense.

you should cast your variable as others have said.

Answer (score 1):

Casting is a compile type operation, you're telling the compiler: "This object is a [insert type here]".  `GetType()` is a runtime method that returns a specific type (the type `Type`).  So there are a couple of problems, you cannot use the runtime method in a compile time construct.  Second, you would actually in this case be casting (assuming this was possible) to `Type` rather than say `String` (assuming `GetType()` returned `String`).

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but this is probably what you want to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx

Also, I think you might not be understanding what `var` is (based on some of your comments).  You "cast things to var", var is essentially a shortcut which allows the compiler to infer the type.  So something like this:

```
var myString = "this is a test";
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
string myString = "this is a test";
```